# Why n++ not work when it is an argument for sizeof() function?

Tags: c, sizeof

```
int main() {
    int n = 1;
    sizeof(n++);
    printf("%d",n);
    return 0;
}
```

It's part of my code. The output is 1. But why is `n` not increased by 1?
I tried that for other functions but for others output was 2.

Comment: `sizeof n++` equates to *"sizeof type(n++)"* (if this existed). the size of of a type does not change no matter what value it has: `sizeof 42` == `sizeof -3` == `sizeof isalpha('x')` == `sizeof (int)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because, `sizeof` is not a function, it is a compile time operator, ans unless the operand is a VLA, the operand is not evaluated at runtime.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.3.4

> [...] If the type of the operand is a variable length array
>   type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result is an
>   integer constant.

To add a little on *why* it does not need to evaluate the operand, from the semantics of the operand,

> [....] The size is determined from the type of
>   the operand. [...]

and, the type of the operand is fixed and known at compile time (unless a VLA), so it does not need to evaluate the operand to perform it's job anyway. In your case, since `n` is of type `int`

```
 sizeof (n++);
```

is just the same as

```
 sizeof (int);
```

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof` is not a function, it's an operator.

`sizeof(n++)` is equivalent to `sizeof n++`, which (since `n` is an `int`) is equivalent to `sizeof (int)`.

`sizeof` only looks at the type of its operand; it doesn't evaluate expressions.

(Unless variable-length arrays are involved, but we're going to ignore that for now.)

Answer (score 1):

Because `sizeof` is not a function, but an operator. It's argument has no side effects.

Comment: Most of the time the operand of `sizeof` has no side effects. However, in `int n = 3; sizeof(int [n++]); printf("%d\n", n);`, `n` is changed, and “4” is printed.